# Why do I get an integer overflow, and how do I fix it?

Tags: c, overflow

Trying to compile the following line in my code breaks:

```
printf("%llu\n", 0x12345678 * 0x12345678);
```

I get this:

```
program.c:45:34: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
     printf("%llu\n", (0x12345678 * 0x12345678));
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `0x12345678 * 0x12345678` --> `0x12345678ULL * 0x12345678`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I've never seen that before, but it fixes the warning. Thank you.

Comment: @bjd2385 The key here is to understand what type that C uses for the _calculation_, which is determined based on the types of the operands. What type you store the end result in doesn't affect the type used for the calculation.

Comment: @Lundin That makes a lot of sense. Even though my answer has been down voted (unsurprisingly), I've still learned an important concept here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[After accept correction per [@Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253787/why-do-i-get-an-integer-overflow-and-how-do-i-fix-it/41254784?noredirect=1#comment69719652_41254784)] comment

On your machine, `0x12345678` is narrower than `unsigned long long` - certainly a `signed long` or maybe `int`.

A `signed long  * signed long` is still an `signed long` and can suffer from *signed integer* overflow, which is UB.  The range of your `signed long` is less than the mathematical product of `0x12345678 * 0x12345678`. By using `ULL` suffix, the math is done at least with `unsigned long long` math.  [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253787/why-do-i-get-an-integer-overflow-and-how-do-i-fix-it#comment69708162_41253787)

```
printf("%llu\n", 0x12345678ULL * 0x12345678);
// or if the constant can not be changed
printf("%llu\n", 1ULL * SOME_BIG_CONSTANT * SOME_BIG_CONSTANT);
```

---

Pedantic note: When printing integer types that *might* wider than `int/unsigned`, insure the final computed result matches the specifier.  Consider that SOME_BIG_CONSTANT might be wider than `unsigned long long`.  Or leave the cast off, and cope with the potential compiler warning.

```
printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long) (1ULL * SOME_BIG_CONSTANT * SOME_BIG_CONSTANT));
```

See also [Why write 1,000,000,000 as 1000*1000*1000 in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40633261/2410359)
and [There are reasons not to use 1000 * 1000 * 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/2410359)

Comment: `0x12345678` is of type (signed) `int` on a 32 bit machine, not unsigned. Unlike `0x82345678` which is of type `unsigned int`.

Comment: @lundin - agreed.