# Overflow appears even when using unsigned long int

Tags: c

When I make the following calculation:

```
unsigned long long int data_size = 60123456 * 128 * sizeof(double);
printf("data_size= %llu  \n", data_size);
```

I surprisingly get overflow warning:

```
test.c:20:49: warning: overflow in expression; result is -894132224 with type 'int' [-Winteger-overflow]
    unsigned long long int data_size = 60123456 * 128 * sizeof(double);
                                                ^
1 warning generated.
```

I cannot understand why this error appears even though I am using `unsigned long long int`! Can someone explain why? Thank you

Comment: Try `60123456ULL`.

Comment: It's the (sub-)expression `60123456 * 128` that the compiler complains about. Try making one of the values an `unsigned long long` with the `ULL` suffix.

Comment: `T x = expression;` means to compute expression, and then initialize `x` with the result of that expression.  The evaluation of an expression is not affected by what is done with the result afterwards.

Comment: Which platform ? which compiler and version ? until c99 byte <= short <= int <= long

Comment: Your EXPRESSION is signed, not unsigned.

Answer (score 45):

Overflow occurs *before* value is assigned to the variable. To avoid that use long long suffix:

```
60123456LL * 128 * sizeof(double)
```

(comments also suggest ULL which is not necessary here because values are within signed range, but that would be the generic way to go)

Comment: Mentionning that U is not needed: +1

Comment: @glglgl  `U` is not need here in this case, yet `U` is better for the generic case.   Consider `60123456LL * 300000000000`.  Without the `U`, this again is signed integer overflow even though the math product fits in `unsigned long long`.  Best to do the math in a least with width of the target type.

Comment: @chux agreed, pretty much all the coding guidelines I've ever seen don't appreciate silent signed -> unsigned conversion.

Answer (score 18):

You are converting to "long long" too late. `60123456 * 128` is still an overflowing int expression.

Try `60123456LL * 128` instead. (LL because the resulting value is not guaranteed to fit in a long.)

Comment: `LL` is useful to get closer to a calculation that fits, yet the target type is `unsigned long long`, not `long long`.  ULL is best for general computation of constants meant for an `unsigned long long` target.

Answer (score 12):

```
unsigned long long int data_size = 60123456 * 128 * sizeof(double);  // trouble-some code
```

The type of destination `unsigned long long int data_size =` is irrelevant to the product calculation `60123456 * 128 * sizeof(double)`.

Best to insure math is done using at least the size of the target type to avoid overflow.  In OP's case, that implies a constant with `LLU`.

---

There are 2 product calculations, each with their own type math.

`60123456` is an `int` or `long` depending on `int` range.  Let us assume it is an `int`.

`60123456 * 128` is an `int * int`. The math product `7695802368` exceeds 32-bit *signed integer*  range, thus **signed integer overflow** or undefined behavior (UB) with a 32-bit `int`.

If `60123456 * 128` did not overflow, says 64-bit `int`, than the next multiplication would be `* sizeof(double);` and so `int * size_t` results in a `size_t` type product.

Product calculation should use at least `unsigned long long` math as below:

```
unsigned long long int data_size = 1LLU * 60123456 * 128 * sizeof(double);

// or
unsigned long long int data_size = 60123456LLU * 128 * sizeof(double);

// or 
unsigned long long int data_size = 60123456;
data_size *= 128 * sizeof(double);

// or avoiding naked magic numbers
#define A_HEIGHT 60123456
#define A_WIDTH 128
unsigned long long int data_size = 1LLU * A_HEIGHT * A_WIDTH * sizeof(double);
```

---

The `sizeof (double)` hints that code is attempting to find the size of some 2D-like structure.  I'd expect code like the following.  Notice the result type of `sizeof` is `size_t`, so the product math is done using at least `size_t` math.

```
size_t data_size = sizeof(double) * 60123456 * 128;
printf("data_size= %zu\n", data_size);
```

---

See also [Why write 1,000,000,000 as 1000*1000*1000 in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40633059/2410359)
 and my answer [reasons not to use 1000 * 1000 * 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633059/why-write-1-000-000-000-as-100010001000-in-c/40637622#40637622) for applicable details..

Comment: Just a small remark: *`int * size_t` resulting in a `size_t` type product.*  You are skipping a step that might be of importance: `int * size_t` first converts `int` to `size_t` and then performs `size_t * size_t -> size_t`.  If the `int` is negative, the result may be surprising.

Comment: @chqrlie True.  That surprising outcome is more likely with `int` objects unlike the positive `int` _integer constants_ here.

Answer (score 4):

The constants `60123456` and `128` are of type `int`, therefore the expression `60123456 * 128` is also of type `int`.  The value of this expression would overflow the range of an `int`.  The compiler is able to detect it in this case because both operands are constants.

You should use the `ULL` suffix on the first operand to make the type of the constant `unsigned long long`.  That way it matches the type being assigned to.  Then for any operation involving this value, the other operand will be promoted to `unsigned long long` before the operation is applied and you won't have any overflow.

So the resulting expression should look like this:

```
unsigned long long int data_size = 60123456ULL * 128 * sizeof(double);
```

Answer (score 3):

The lexer attaches types on constants during translation phase 7 (conversion of preprocessing tokens into C tokens.) cf ISO9899 `5.1.1.2  Translation phases`.  As the others said, the lexer will attach on your constants the type `int` instead of `unsigned long long` as you wish, and in order for the `default arithmetic conversions` to generate a constant of type `unsigned long long` on the right side of the assignment you need to say to the lexer to attach the type `unsigned long long` on at least one constant from the operation `*` that generates the overflow, so by writing `60123456ULL * 128` or `60123456 * 128ULL` or both.