# why 1024*1024*1024*2 != 1024*1024*1024*2

Tags: c, integer-overflow

at the beginning, I write a demo to get 2G memory, but the I got a problem like this, I don't know why, what different of num1, num2, num3?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    unsigned long num1 = 1024*1024*1024*2;
    unsigned long num2 = 1024*1024*1024*2.0;
    unsigned long num3 = 1024*1024*1024;
    num3 *= 2;
    printf("num1:%lu\n num2:%lu\n num3:%lu\n", num1, num2, num3);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
num1:18446744071562067968
num2:2147483648
num3:2147483648
```

Comment: `1024*1024*1024*2` this calculation is performed with `int` data type, since all literals are or type `int`. Consequently, you get _signed integer overflow_, which, I guess is **undefined** (in C++ it's undefined behavior, not sure about C).

Comment: dont you get a warning?

Comment: very similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281718/overflow-appears-even-when-using-unsigned-long-int

Comment: this code gives a warning: `test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:3:40: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
     unsigned long num1 = 1024*1024*1024*2;` always enable warnings.

Comment: I got this, but I don't know why in that time, but i find the answer now , anyway thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The first line, `unsigned long num1 = 1024*1024*1024*2;`, initializes an `unsigned long` (`num1`) with an `int`. The computation `1024*1024*1024*2` has type `int` because all the values are `int` literals. Use the `UL` suffix on at least one of them to make it `unsigned long`:

```
unsigned long num1 = 1024UL*1024*1024*2;
```

As a precaution, you can prefer putting the suffix on the first value because of the left-to-right associativity of multiplication. That way, all these multiplications are done between values of type `unsigned long` instead of `int`.

As for why the other two methods work: the second line initializes `num2` with a `double`, which has enough precision to produce the correct value in this case; the third line initializes `num3` with an `int` as well, but `1024*1024*1024` is representable by a 32-bit `int` (it's 2^30, which is less than 2^31-1). The multiplication by 2 after that is done on an `unsigned long`, so it works as expected.

Comment: The UL is a good idea, yet `1024*1024*1024` is still calculated using `int` math.   This overflows 16-bit `int`, common in embedded processors and with other less obvious constants.  Best to have the lead constant as `UL` as in `1024UL*1024*1024*2;` so all the computation is done using `unsigned long` math.  [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/2410359)

Comment: I know, what a simple solution! thank you.that help me a lot.