# A dynamic 1D array in C don't want to ingest each character of a file in each of his boxes

Tags: c, file, dynamic-arrays

In C, I want to fill a dynamic array with each character of a file in each of his boxes.
But instead, when I print my array I have:

```
0 = [] 
1 = [] 
2 = [] 
3 = [] 
4 = [] 
5 = [] 
6 = [] 
7 = [] 
8 = [] 
9 = []
```

I have no compilation errors, but valgrind said that I have a:

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
```

in my main at the printf.
That's strange, because even with an initialisation in my main:

```
array_valid_char = NULL;
```

valgrind keeps getting me that error.
And even if I change to:

```
printf("%d = [%d] \n", i, array_valid_char[i]);
```

the display is the same.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* f(char* name_file_in)
{
    FILE *file_in;
    int* array_valid_char = malloc(10 * sizeof(int*));
    int read_char;
    file_in = fopen(name_file_in,"rb");
    if(file_in)
    {
        while ((read_char = fgetc(file_in)) != EOF)
        {
            *(array_valid_char++) = read_char;
        }
    }
    if(file_in){fclose(file_in);}
    return array_valid_char;
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    int *array_valid_char = malloc(10 * sizeof(int*));
    array_valid_char = f(argv[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d = [%c] \n", i, array_valid_char[i]);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Consider what happens if "if my file is: abcdefghik" is only the beginning and in addition there was a following `'\n'`.  Allocated memory assigned to `array_valid_char` overflows leading to _undefined behavior_ (UB).

Comment: @user3121023 then `int* array_valid_char` is not the right type.  Allocation should match the `ptr = mallloc(sizeof *ptr * n)` model.

Comment: @user3121023.: Yes

Comment: @user3121023 [sizeof *ptr in your example would be int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48214739/why-dynamic-1d-array-dont-want-to-input-each-character-of-a-file-in-c?noredirect=1#comment83411523_48214739) `sizeof *ptr` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`.  The value, in this case would be the same as `sizeof (int)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to keep track of the beginning of the allocated memory which you didn't. (That original allocated chunks address should be returned ).

```
int* array_valid_char = malloc(10 * sizeof(int*));
int *st = array_valid_char ;

...
return st;
```

Also you have memory leak - you can omit the `malloc` in main().

Also you need to free the dynamically allocated memory when you are done working with it.

```
free(array_valid_char);
```

And also the memory allocation part would be

```
int* array_valid_char = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

or

```
 int* array_valid_char = malloc(10 * sizeof(*array_valid_char));
```

You want array of `int`.

Among other points check the return value of `malloc` and handle it properly.

The correct way to code would be to index into the allocated memory and check whether we are reaching limit of what we allocated - if it is so then reallocate.

<sup>Many of us confine ourselves with the thought that `sizeof( *ptr)*10`
 is only good enough for the clear syntax etc but knowing that `sizeof` returns `size_t` when multiplied this with other value it is less likely to overflow as in opposed to writing the other way round(which was having `int` arithmetic) that's a benefit. (chux)</sup>
<sup>For example: `sizeof(something)*int*int` will do result in operation with `size_t` value which will less likely to overflow that `int*int*sizeof(int)`. In second case `int*int` may overflow.(more likely)</sup>

Comment: @yano Note: Leading with `sizeof *array_valid_char` has advantages when `10` is more complex and large like `sizeof *array_valid_char * 100000 * 100000` as it insures all the math is done with at least `size_t` math and not `int` math - which may overflow.

Comment: @chux oh so you're saying `10 * sizeof(*array_valid_char)` performs integer math whereas `sizeof(*array_valid_char) * 10` performs `size_t` math?

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, the free function must be in my main. Not in my function f. Right?

Comment: @LinuxCrusher.: Yep

Comment: @yano.  No.  `10 * sizeof(*array_valid_char)` will convert `10` to `size_t` and do the math as `size_t * size_t`. No benefit here leading with `10` or `sizeof`.  It is with `int*int*size_t` versus `size_t*int*int` where leading with `sizeof` benefits.  The first can do a `int*int` which may OF, but maybe not if it was `size_t` math.

Comment: @chux.: I guess that is because `*` is left associative - so `int` arithemtic may overflow.

Comment: Yes, The general idea is simple: with math, often good  to insure the math is done with the widest type of the arguments [and the destination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/2410359)

Comment: @chux.: Ah read that answer before. Nice one..yes I get the point.

Comment: @chux.: Thanks again..a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your code:

With `*(array_valid_char++)`, you move your pointer each time you pass on the loop. If you want to use this method, you need to keep a track on the beginning of your array with an other variable. You can also use an iterator `array_valid_char[i]` that starts at 0 and increments it at each loop turn.

In your main, you malloc your array `int *array_valid_char = malloc(10 * sizeof(int*));` but you override it just after with `array_valid_char = f(argv[1]);`. If you malloc your array in a function and send it back with a return, the memory is still allocated.

In printf, `%d` is for display a number and `%c` is for display a character. In your case, you need to use `%c`. In the other case, you will see the [ASCII](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html) value of your character.

By the way, you also use an int array to receive char array. It is not a problem now but for some optimisation, you can use char array to take less memory.

Also, don't forget to `free` the memory you have used when you don't use it anymore, it could be useful in bigger programs.

Comment: I just came up with a solution but with *(array_valid_char++). It is functionning well. Or maybe that's not an optimize way to code?

Comment: @LinuxCrusher *(array_valid_char++) is good. The idea was just to explain you the difference between the two methods.