# What does 1024LL mean in C

Tags: c

I'm looking into fortify issues identified in some open source C code our service uses and see code like this;

```
..
} else if (n < (1024LL*1024*1024)) {
..
```

What is the significance of the LL on 1024LL as opposed to just 1024?
Thanks.

Comment: [This literal suffix table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant#The_type_of_the_integer_constant) could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

LL is a suffix that means long long. In that particular snippet of code, the writer is saying one of the terms is 1024 but stored in a long long way.  C has a rule that says the largest bits of any of the terms will be what it uses when it resolves integer math.  Without the LL, then, 1024 * 1024 * 1024 would just overflow.

Comment: "C has a rule that says the largest bits of any of the terms will be what it uses when it resolves integer math" --> Yes (use highest rank) for 2 terms, no for 3 terms as all are done 2 terms at a time.

Comment: `1024 * 1024 * 1024` would not overflow 32-bit `int`.  Still `1024LL*1024*1024` is a good [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/2410359).