# Multiplying two positive numbers returns negative in C

Tags: c

I don't understand why the code below outputs a negative number

```
int main() {
    int cases = 1000000 * 50;
    int now = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
        now++;
        now = now * now;
        now = now % cases;
        if (now < 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", now);
    return 0;
}
```

output is: `-37008604`

Comment: [Integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) and [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 6):

The posted code has undefined behavior when `now` becomes larger than `sqrt(INT_MAX)`, which is `46340` on 32-bit systems, because signed arithmetic overflow has undefined behavior. The result of computing `now * now` causing an overflow could be a negative number, or an exception or anything else, and computing `now % cases` with a negative `now` produces a number between `-cases+1` and `0`, which is what you observe.

If you use type `long long` for the intermediary result, the program will have defined behavior and output `22152025`:

Note however that you make the assumption that `int` is large enough to represent `50000000`, which the C Standard does not guarantee. For complete portability, you should use type `long` for `now`, `cases` and `i`.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long cases = 1000000L * 50;
    long now = 1;
    for (long i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
        now++;
        now = ((long long)now * now) % cases;
        if (now < 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%ld\n", now);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also note `long` and `long long` can be exactly the same type, and this is generally the case when compiling for 64b.

Comment: " make the assumption that int is large enough to represent 50000000" is interesting as code here also assumes things, and gets away with it with potential `long = int * int;`.  Consider if code was `10000 * 50`.  That `int` * `int` might overflow.  On some unicorn machine with 24-bit `int`, `1000000 * 50` would overflow.  As the left side `long` does not influence the right side, the math on the right should insure the calculation is done using at least the width of the left-side.  Perhaps as `1000000L * 50`?  Issue explored [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/2410359).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: what a sharp eye! I guess this unicorn machine would not even have a friendly compiler warning the user about the overflow in this constant expression :(

Comment: Not so much a sharp eye as a black eye from bugs using narrow math on the right assigning to a wider left side result.  Common enough porting code between 16,32,64 bit processors.

Answer (score 1):

now is going beyond MAX of int. 
Adding following code inside of `for` loop will provide much more information.

```
printf("%d->%d\n", i,now);
```

it indicates:
for 32 bit system - after 4 iteration, your value of now is overflowing the allocated memory of int.

Output after adding debugs.

```
0->4
1->25
2->676
3->458329
4->-37008604
```

Comment: just a detail, *allocated memory of int* is wrongly said for me, *now* can stay in a register