# K&R Milliseconds Calculation - Initialization - Type Conversion

Tags: c

In K&R (second edition) in section 4.9 (pg. 85) when discussing Initialization, an example of calculating the number of milliseconds in a day is given:

```
long day = 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L
```

Why are long literals used here on the RHS of the assignment? In section 2.7 (Type Conversions) on pg 44 the following rules are given:

> If either operand is `long double`, convert the other to `long double
>
> Otherwise if either operand is `double` , convert the other to `double`
>
> Otherwise if either operand is `float`, convert the other to `float`
>
> Otherwise, convert `char` and `short` to `int`
>
> Then, if either operand is `long`, convert the other to `long`.

For the calculation of `long day = ...`, surely `int` literals could be used here? Would they not automatically be converted to `long` based on the rules above?

I wrote the following:

`long day1 = 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L;`

`long day2 = 1000*60*60*24;`

Within the debugger, both `day1` and `day2` were `long`.
What was the purpose of using `long` literals?

Comment: [Why write 1,000,000,000 as 1000*1000*1000 in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/2410359) may be useful.

Comment: Because `1000*60*60*24` _might_ give you 23552 on systems with 16-bit `int`.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that an `int` is 32 bits. That was not the case when K&R was written. Even now, an `int` is allowed to be 16 bits, which is not large enough to hold the number of milliseconds in a day.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1000*60*60*24` is done using `int` math which may overflow when `int` is 16-bit.

`1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L` does not overflow as `long` is at least 32-bit.

---

Code could have been as below to achieve `long` math with all the `L`s.

```
long day = 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24;
```

Comment: So the RHS needs at least one `long` literal to ensure it does not overflow before being assigned to `day`?

Comment: @nate not quite: `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24L` overflows 16-bit math as the product is evaluated left to right.

Comment: Ah ok! Thanks! Accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

In standard C, an `int` is only guaranteed to hold 16 bit values, while a `long` is guaranteed to hold 32 bit values.

K&R predates standard C, but the standard derives from the rules that K&R had in place.  So `long` is required to guarantee the value will fit.