# What's the role of L in modulo 1000000007L?

Tags: c, overflow, modulo

When you're a total noob programming, a lot of things looks like magic,
so solving some classic problems at SPOJ using C language, I found one called [DIAGONAL](https://www.spoj.com/problems/DIG/).

After some attempts I gave up and went searching for solutions and I found [this one](https://github.com/sranshous/SPOJ/blob/master/DIG/DIG.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num_cases, i;
    long long mod_by = 24*1000000007L;
    scanf("%d", &num_cases);

    long long n;
    long long answer;
    for(i = 0; i < num_cases; i++) {
        scanf("%lld", &n);
        long long x = (n*(n-1)) % (mod_by);
        long long y = (x*(n-2)) % (mod_by);
        long long z = (y*(n-3)) % (mod_by);
        answer = z / 24;
        printf("%lld\n", answer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

At first glance I thought that `L` with the modulo was some kind of mistake made by the user who posted the code (haha who would mix numbers with letters this way?! nonsense! -thought the noob-), but when I fixed the (many) wrongs in my code and used this modulo, it didn't work without the magic `L` (I got Wrong Answer).
Then I substituted the L with the **`ASCII`** code number (because well, maybe it was that!) and it also didn't work.

Since then I'm trying to understand what is the logic behind this. How can I get the same results removing this L?

It's not like one just woke up in the morning and "uhm, maybe if I add this `L` it will work", but I just couldn't find other examples of this (random letter added to a large number for calculations) *googling*.

Comment: An important difference between this post and the dupe is that the suffix has a following insufficient effect due to a calculation whereas the dupe is a simple constant.

Answer (score 3):

`long long mod_by = 24*1000000007L;` is a problem.

The `L` suffix insures the constant `1000000007` is at least of type `long`.<sup>1</sup>  Without the `L`, the type may have been `int` or `long`.

Yet since `long` **may only be 32-bit**, the ~36-bit product can readily overflow `long` math leading to *undefined behavior* (UB).

The assignment to a `long long` happens after and does not affect the type nor range of the multiplication.

Code should use `LL` to form the product and protect against overflow.

```
long long mod_by = 24LL*1000000007;
// or
long long mod_by = 24*1000000007LL;
```

In general, make certain the calculation occurs at least with the width of the destination.

See also [Why write 1,000,000,000 as `1000*1000*1000` in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/2410359).

---

<sup>1</sup> In OP's case, apparently `int` is 32-bit and `long` is 64-bit so code "worked" with a `L` and failed without it.  Yet porting this code to a 32-bit `long` implementation, code fails with or without an `L`.  Insure `long long` math with an `LL` constant.

Answer (score 1):

`L` is a suffix that means that the number is of type `long`, otherwise it will default to type `int` that means the result of the operation `24 * 1000000007` will also be of type `int`.

As an `int` is usually 4 bytes in size the result will overflow, this happens before it being assigned to `mod_by`, and for that reason it invokes undefined behavior.

As the result of the arithmetic operation is converted to the larger type, e.g:

`int * int = int`

`int * long = long`

For the result of the operation to be of type `long` one of the operands must also be of type `long`.

Note that `long` is not guaranteed to have 8 bytes in size, [the minimum allowed size for a `long` is 4 bytes](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/), so you can invoke the same undefined behavior deppending on the platform where you compile your program.

Using `LL` for `long long` will be more portable.

Answer (score 1):

The `L` suffix when applied to an integer constant means the constant has type `long`.

This is done to prevent overflow when the value is multiplied by 24.  Without the suffix, two constants of type `int` are multiplied giving an `int` result.  Assuming 32 is 32 bits, the result will overflow the range of an `int` (2<sup>31</sup>-1) causing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

By making the constant have type `long`, assuming a `long` is 64 bits, it allows the multiplication to be done using and type and therefore not cause overflow and give you the correct value.