# Strange overflow assigning 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, overflow

```
void main()
{
    long long ll = 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; 
    unsigned long long ull = (2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
    std::cout << ll << "\n" << ull;
}
```

My output with Visual Studio 2019 is

```
 -2147483648
18446744071562067968
```

I have no idea why overflow is happening here, please help

Comment: `main` should return `int`.

Comment: In both cases you are doing the calculation as an int and overflowing. All the numbers on the right hand side are integers. Try `std::cout << 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024ull << std::endl;`

Comment: See also [Why write 1,000,000,000 as 1000*1000*1000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/2410359).

Comment: Tip: Use things like `uint64_t ull` from [`<cstdint>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) instead of madness like `unsigned long long long long plz be long ull` where it's unclear what you'll actually get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In both cases the calculation is done using integers because all the values on the right are integer literals. `2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024` is `2,147,483,648` which 1 larger than the max 32 bit int so this part of the calculation is overflowing. To fix do the first calculation as long long using `long long ll = 2LL * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;` and the second calculation as an unsigned long long using  `unsigned long long ull = 2ULL * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;`

You can learn more about integer literals here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Here is the fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long ll = 2LL * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; 
    unsigned long long ull = 2ULL * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    std::cout << ll << "\n" << ull;
}
```

I put an online version of this fixed code here:
https://ideone.com/5QkEls

Comment: Makes more sense to _lead_ the multiplication chain with `LL` so `2LL * 1024 * 1024 * 1024`.  Now the product is correct even if `int` was 16-bit.