# How to calculate maximum number of elements that can be allocated in a rte_mempool?

Tags: c, dpdk

Let's say we have 16x1GB hugepages available for DPDK. We want to use as much memory as possible for a single mempool of mbufs. How can we calculate the maximum number of packets that will lead to a successful rte_mempool creation, given the maximum packet size?

For simplicity assume both private data size and cache size is zero:

```c
const uint16_t max_rx_pkt_size = 9216;
// We have 16GB of hugepage memory
const uint32_t hugepage_size_bytes = 16U * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
// How to calculate the max number of packets that we can allocate?
const uint32_t num_packets = hugepage_size_bytes / max_rx_pkt_size;
rte_mempool *mp = rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("rx_packet_pool", num_packets,
                                            0 /* Cache size */, 0 /* Private size */,
                                            max_rx_pkt_size, rte_socket_id());
```

The above call to `rte_pktmbuf_pool_create()` fails due to lack of memory, rte_errno is set to ENOMEM.

Clearly DPDK allocates some memory internally for its data structures, so we can't allocate a rte_mempool that occupies 100% of our hugepage memory.

The current workaround we are using is to reduce `hugepage_size_bytes`  before we calculate `num_packets` :
`hugepage_size_bytes -= (hugepage_size_bytes / 32);`
Then we end up with a smaller value of `num_packets` and `rte_pktmbuf_pool_create()` succeeds.

However when we changed `max_rx_pkt_size` to a different value, say 1460 then mempool allocation fails. This is not a good approach. Is there a way we can programmatically check (or at least estimate with certainty) the maximum amount of mbufs that can be allocated based on hugepage memory size?

Answer (score -1):

At least this problem with OP's approach:

**`unsigned` overflow**

> The above call to `rte_pktmbuf_pool_create()` fails due to lack of memory, `rte_errno` is set to `ENOMEM`.

Might it failed due to the size is zero?

With 32-bit `unsigned`, the product is zero.

```
16U * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 // overflow
// same as
0u
```

Instead use [wider types when forming the constant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/2410359) and saving the product:

```
// const uint32_t hugepage_size_bytes = 16U * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
const unsigned long long hugepage_size_bytes = 16LLU * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

// Maybe add a check
if (hugepage_size_bytes / (UINT32_MAX + 1ull) >= max_rx_pkt_size) {
  Handle_size_too_big();
}

const uint32_t num_packets = hugepage_size_bytes / max_rx_pkt_size;
```

---

**Real allocation?**

I am unfamiliar with `rte_pktmbuf_pool_create()`, yet with various allocation tests, sometimes, memory is not allocated until *used*.

The concern of [Why is malloc not "using up" the memory on my computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19991623/2410359) may apply.

---

**Minor: Type**

One example of [`rte_pktmbuf_pool_create()`](https://github.com/ceph/dpdk/blob/master/lib/librte_mbuf/rte_mbuf.c) uses `unsigned n` and not `uint32_t n`

```
struct rte_mempool *
rte_pktmbuf_pool_create(const char *name, unsigned n,
    unsigned cache_size, uint16_t priv_size, uint16_t data_room_size,
    int socket_id)
```

... so I recommend to match types.

```
// const uint32_t num_packets = hugepage_size_bytes / max_rx_pkt_size;
const usigned num_packets = hugepage_size_bytes / max_rx_pkt_size;
```

---

**Details**

For better assessment "The current workaround we are using", please post more complete sample code.