# Segmentation fault in collatz function

Tags: c, function, segmentation-fault, collatz

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#define max 100000000
int64_t table[max];
int64_t collatz(int64_t a);
int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    if (argc !=3)
    {
        printf("ERROR\nUsage: ./collatz {argv1} {argv2}\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int64_t maxlen = 0;
    int64_t num1 = atoi(argv[1]);
    int64_t num2 = atoi(argv[2]);
    if (num1 < 1 || num2 < 1 || num1 > max || num2 > max)
    {
        printf("%"PRId64"\n",maxlen);
        return 2;
    }
    int64_t i;
    for (i=num1;i<=num2;i++)
    {
        int64_t len = collatz(i);
        if (len > maxlen)
        {
            maxlen = len;
        }
    }
    printf("%" PRId64 "\n", maxlen);
    return 0;
}
int64_t collatz(int64_t a)
{
    if (a <= max)
    {
        if(table[a] != 0)
        {
            return table[a];
        }
    }
    int64_t len = 1;
    if (a != 1)
    {
        if (a%2==0)
            len += collatz(a/2);
        else
            len += collatz(a*3+1);
    }
    if (a <= max)
    {
        table[a]=len;
    }
    return len;
}
```

When I remove the last if statement in the collatz function I get a segmentation fault. I can't understand this because the array size is 100.000.000 and I never allow a number bigger than that to enter. Also I know a number can exceed the limits inside the function e.g. 99.999.999 but I am pretty sure a number higher than 100.000.000 will never meet the last if statement in the function, but if I remove it somehow I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: You use recursion, and it's not a tail recursion. Compiler can't optimize it to iterative execution, so stack is used. Stack size is limited.

Comment: @dimich that will not cause a segmentation fault, though.

Comment: @Judge: dimich is pointing out that each recursive call to `collatz` uses stack space, and only a modest amount of space is reserved for the stack (last time I checked, the defaults were 8 MiB on macOS, 2 MiB on Linux, and 1 MiB on Windows, if I recall correctly). Your simple routine might need only 16 bytes of stack per call, or 32 if you are using a 64-bit architecture, so a chain of 131,072 calls will exhaust the stack. You should rewrite the code to be iterative, not recursive.

Comment: OT: Suggestion. `#define max (100 * 1000 * 1000)` Don't make your reader squint to have to start counting how many zeros are there... Better yet, use `#define max 1e8`

Comment: @Fe2O3 Deeper: Code like `100 * 1000` overflows with 16-bit `int` and `10 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000` risks overflow with 32-bit `int`.  Whole number constants much bigger than like 9e15 risks imprecision.  Fortunately C23 may provide a ` to separate as desired.  Here I would use `#define max ((size_t)100 * 1000 * 1000` and let the compiler warn about 16-bit `size_t` if needed.  [not to use 1000 * 1000 * 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/2410359).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Good that you point that out. A trap for the unwary (like me), esp. as more and more bits are being commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

In the `collatz` function you have `table` as an array of size `max`. That means the maximum valid index is `max - 1`. Yet, you test that `a` is less than *or equal to* `max`. This permits an out of bounds array access and a segmentation fault is a possible result.

> ```
>     if (a <= max)
>     {
>         if(table[a] != 0)
>         {
>             return table[a];
>         }
>     }
> ```